# It's Top of the...Oops!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

Welcome to the Hit Parade on KIGI radio. 
That completes our rundown of the top 10-[there's some absolute classics in there this week! And what a bunch of new entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXppo.jpg) as you can see if you've been following us during the programme! 
This week we have a new number 1 song and would you believe it-it's one of this week's new entries! Straight in at the top it's....

*crrrk....static....radio station disappears into oblivion*

Never mind...you don't have to frantically try and call them up to find out this week's chart topper. Because fortunately, it's logical that this song should have made it to the top, so you can work out which of the new entries has made it to Number 1 and why!

Edited to include listings here for those who don't wanna go hunting:

```
2 Police-Geno
3 Dana-Bright Eyes
4 Mud-Oh Boy!
5 ABBA-SOS
6 Blondie-Heart o'Glass
7 Elton John-I'm Still Standing
8 ELO/Darts-Theme from the Movie 'Xanadu'
9 Wizzard-Call Me
```

And the new entries:

```
The Beatles-Penny Lane/Strawberry Fields Forever
Queen-Dancing Queen
Status Quo-Caroline
David Essex-Hold Me Close
Tina Turner-The Best
The Four Seasons-Sherry
```

Comment: Why don't you use the advertisement-free `stack.imgur.com` like everyone else? It's even quite easy to embed images stored there, so we don't have to follow a link and can see the image directly in the post.

Comment: By the way.. is it me or are some track titles fake? Bright Eyes is sung by Art Garfunkel, The Police never sung a song called Geno and "Darts-Theme from the Movie" should be replaced by Olivia Newton?

Or is this part of the puzzle ;)

Comment: It's all part of the puzzle-the artists and songs are exactly as depicted. I tried using imgur stack,but got a funny message telling me I shouldn't be there-curious.I'll give it another try.

Comment: @Kit-Ginevra: You don't need to actually go to stack.imgur.com, just add/upload the image to your question and it will automatically create the link for you, easy as that.

Comment: Any reason why there are 9 songs in a top 10?

Comment: [Mud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8gf0mc-ITI)  just became my favorite antidote for Devo O.D.

Comment: There are 9 songs because the puzzle would not work with 10. No.10 was...let's say interrupted by another burst of static so you didn't get to hear it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I have solved this problem.

So, this is a problem related to

> finding the 'digital root' of the characters. What this means is that we have to keep on summing numbers until we get a single digit number...that is Digital Root of 123 would be 1+2+3=6 , while Digital Root of 547 would be 5+4+7=16=1+6=7...So basically the iterated sum of digits.

Now, in this case , we have to apply the same concept and all we need to do is

> convert the letters of the alphabet in the string to numbers...(ignoring the special characters like "-", or "/" )...with positional index numbers as in { A=1, B=2, C=3.....,X=24, Y=25, Z=26}...and then find the Digital Root of the string.

Performing this operation on the string Police-Geno we have,

> (16+15+12+9+3+5+7+5+14+15) % 9 = 2.... That's the no. 2 song right ? ;)
>  If you are wondering what % is btw , then it's called the modulo operator , that is a % b is the remainder when a is divided by b. It can be shown that Digital Root of any number n = n % 9....

Next, doing the same thing on Dana-Bright Eyes we find

> its Digital Root = (4+1+14+1+2+18+9+7+8+20+5+25+5+19) % 9 = 138 % 9 = 3...And guess what?  We can see that it's number 3 on the list.

So, we have cracked it, haven't we...

> We can likewise check that Digital Root of all songs in the list correspond to their positions in the list...

And so, all we need is to find...

> A string from the new entries' list whose digital root equals 1.

Checking through the list of new entries, we easily find, that for the song...

> "The Beatles-Penny Lane/Strawberry Fields Forever" we have Digital Root
> = (496 % 9) = 1. SO WE ARE DONE !!!!

THE NUMBER ONE SONG IN THE LIST

> (And it's a new entry) is:
>  "The Beatles-Penny Lane/Strawberry Fields Forever"

That's our answer,and this cipher, I feel is successfully cracked.

The Idea First came to my mind when @Kit-Ginevra said that the cipher won't work for 10 songs...;)....but would for 9 songs...

> that's when digital roots first came to my mind.

Please do read the answer and leave your thoughts in the comments as I am new to The Puzzling StackExchange Family. Thank You. :)

Comment: oh my eyes....!

Comment: Well done +1 and Welcome to PSE! You can go through the edits Rubio made to your answer for future reference :-)

Comment: And also try not to use Capital and Bold letters. They are seen as equivalent to shouting.

Comment: Ya, please do teach me...how to "write" the answers...@Sid, I can't see some lines of my answer on the laptop screen after Rubio edited it...only yellow patches instead...Why is that ... Would you please explain...what do i need to do to see the characters there ? :)

Comment: Oh okay...i see i just need to hover over that yellow patch...but how to bring them in my ans ? :)

Comment: That is called "Spoiler text/tag(Not sure)". That means, say I want to solve the puzzle on my own and don't want to look at your answer. Hence, I won't hover above the "yellow patch". That is important to avoid spoiling the answer for others. Don't worry, the text is in the answer and the OP will just have to hover above the patch to see it.